# Несогласованное определение или дополнение?

Tags: определения, дополнение

***А всё потому что слушать гораздо труднее, чем говорить, так как скорость говорения в 4 раза меньше скорости мышления.***

Чем являются в предложении "говорения" и "мышления"? Несогласованные определения или дополнения?

Где-то находила такую информацию:

> При существительных с конкретно-предметным или вещественным значением
> родительный, обозначающий лицо, которому принадлежит данный предмет,
> считается несогласованным определением: книга товарища, дом отца,
> колпак повара и т. п. (чей?) Наоборот, при существительных, называющих
> лицо, родительный, обозначающий предмет, которым владеет данное лицо,
> либо ограничивающий сферу его деятельности, считается приименным
> дополнением: хозяин дома, командир корабля, директор школы, учитель
> физики и т. п.

По аналогии решила, что скорость в некотором роде принадлежность говорения, ее параметр и поэтому "говорения" скорее определение. Но все может оказаться иначе.

Comment: Замена на прилагательное не всегда срабатывает, по-моему. Например, скамья у ворот - это же не приворотная или привратная скамья. И все же "у ворот" является определением. Сон до рассвета, книга об открытиях, человек в очках... Здесь существительные трудно заменить на прилагательные, и все же это определения. Поэтому я перестала полагаться на такой способ.

Comment: Я согласна с тем, что эта тема далеко не простая. Грамматический разбор часто делается формально, в разных источниках объясняется по-разному, но при этом  нет системы, нет понимания приципиального различия между этими терминами. Я бы сказала, что нет единой непротиворечивой теории. Поэтому для удобства часто пользуются такими понятиями, как объектное определение или определительное дополнение, что позволяет не решать задачу, а попросту уйти от этого решения. Поэтому мне хотелось бы услышать интересный ( хорошо бы креативный) ответ на эту тему.

Comment: Тогда предложу другой метод, может он сработает. С известными поправками: Если в соответствующем английском предложении (при множественном или единственном числе) вы ставите определенный артикуль, то это определение. Если неопрделенный артикуль (или нулевой) то не определение. The speed of a talk -- Здесь говорение позволяет поставить перед скоростью определенный артикуль, значит говорение это определение. The sons of their father. Аналогично отец определяет всех своих сыновей. Но a son of his father - один из сыновей отца, по-прежнему определение (см мн. число выше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, это какие-то условности - что к чему относить. Они ни на что не влияют.
Ну, если кому-то будет легче, то можно соотносить по такому правилу (хотя я не уверен что так принято):

Колпак повара = Поварский колпак. Значит определение.

Книга Пети = Петина книга. Значит определение.

Учитель физики != Физиковский учитель. Значит дополнение.

Скорость мышления/мысли != Мышленческая/мысленная скорость. Значит дополнение.

Скорость говорения/речи/разговора != Разговорная/речевая/говорительная скорость. Значит дополнение.

Comment: У меня возникла такая мысль. Применить все же этот способ к словосочетаниям, аналогичным  "скорости говорения" и "скорости мышления". Какой-нибудь физический параметр и то, что он измеряет: рост человека и человеческий рост, масса атома и атомная масса - иногда вполне себе получается переделать в определение, но чаще нет, например, длина пути, температура воздуха. Я вообще задумалась, почему такие словосочетания не являются цельными словосочетаниями по типу - начало дня, много стульев и т.п. По мне так это было бы логично.

Comment: Начало дня было долгим. -- Это не цельное сочетание. Здесь долгость свойство самого начала. Аналогично и с "множество стульев было большим". Аналогично и "скорость поезда была большой".

Comment: Открываются новые горизонты. Я думала, что подобные словосочетания по умолчанию цельные. Но вообще согласна с Вашими рассуждениями.

Answer (score 3):

**ЧАСТЬ 1. ИНФОРМАЦИОННЫЙ МАТЕРИАЛ ДЛЯ ОТВЕТА**

**1. О валентности в лингвистике** (как применить термин "валентность" для различения дополнения и определения)

В лингвистику понятие валентности впервые ввёл С. Д. Кацнельсон (1948 год). В настоящее время оно достаточно известно, им пользуются многие авторы.
Действительно, между химическим соединениями и словосочетаниями в языке есть нечто общее, и **термин из области точной науки можно считать полезным для языкознания.** В частности,  валентность можно было бы использовать в теме, связанной с различением дополнения и определения, в том числе в школьной практике.

2. В учебнике для вузов можно прочитать следующее: **Дополнение** –  это второстепенный член предложения, называющий лицо, предмет или явление, на которое распространяется действие или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.

Сказано хорошо, но не очень понятно. Поэтому использовать его в практических целях довольно сложно. Предлагаемые частные регламентации не всегда достоверны и проблему решают формально, без понимания смыла:  зачем мы вообще занимаемся различением этих понятий.

3. Я же сделаю попытку **применить термин валентности** (подчеркиваю, это только моя собственная попытка сделать это). Поэтому ответ **СТРОГО ФАКУЛЬТАТИВНЫЙ** и рассчитан на людей, которым интересна эта тема, которые могли бы дополнить ее своими  собственными размышлениями.
4. Все мы слышали **о переходных глаголах,** требующих обязательного прямого дополнения. Попробуем назвать это активной (незакрытой) валентностью глагола. Объект дополняет значение глагола, которое без него не раскрыто в полной мере. Об этом нам указывает и словарная статья.

А как рассматривать словосочетания, в которых **предмет (существительное)  управляет объектом (другим существительным)?** Вероятно,  предмет тоже может требовать обязательного объекта, другими словами, иметь незакрытую валентность.

Например, существительное ***ножка***. Из словаря: НОЖКА, 2. Опора, нижняя часть (мебели, утвари и т.п.). Н. стула, кровати, дивана, шкафа.  3. Нижняя часть гриба, а также стебель растения.  И т.д.

Здесь объект необходим, иначе неясно, о какой ножке идет речь.  Но после образования словосочетания **активная валентность закрывается**, теперь оно имеет понятный смысл и его можно распространить  различными определениями: витая ножка стула, тонкая ножка цветка.

**ЧАСТЬ 2. ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

1. Рассмотрим заданные словосочетания: ***скорость говорения и скорость мышления.***  Мышление будем рассматривать как процесс создания информации, а говорение –  как процесс передачи информации. Тогда получаем сложные словосочетания:  скорость создания/передачи информации.
2. Создать/передать информацию. Это **переходные глаголы, прямое дополнение**, в сочетаниях с управляющим существительным функция дополнения сохраняется
3. Из словаря:  **СКОРОСТЬ,**  1. Степень быстроты движения кого-, чего-л. или распространения чего-л., а также совершения какого-л. действия, протекания процесса.

Здесь валентность **также незакрытая,**  термин обязательно **должен быть дополнен**.  И тогда мы получаем сложное словосочетание без открытой валентности:  скорость ***создания/передачи информации***. Или другими словами: ***скорость мышления и скорость говорения.***

4. Следовательно, **это дополнения,** но не определения. Определить такие сочетания можно количественно: маленькая скорость, большая скорость.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ к ответу**

1. Это общий принцип решения, но таким  же образом можно решать **конкретные** задачи, в том числе **парные** варианты.

Я приведу такой пример:

(1) ***Речь (чья?) актера N** произвела на всех большое впечатление.*  Это определение, значение принадлежности.

(2) ***Речь (кого?) актера** (человека данной профессии) всегда образна и интересна.* Это дополнение, так как  имеется в виду особая (актерская) речь, а не речь человека вообще.

Здесь уже словосочетание ***речь актера***  имеет **полностью выраженное значение и закрытую валентность.** Также и относительный суффикс СК в прилагательном ***актерский*** отчасти подсказывает нам это решение.

2. **Примечание.** Разумеется, говорить о валентности вслух ни в коем случае не следует (это личное знание), нужно использовать **общепринятую терминологию.**

**Дополнение** расширяет (**дополняет**) значение предмета до более полного смысла, а **определение** классифицирует (**делит**) предметы на группы **по какому-либо параметру** (размер, цвет, вес, материал, принадлежность и т.д.).

Comment: _Sharon: (2) Речь (кого?) актера (человека данной профессии) всегда образна и интересна. **Это дополнение, так как имеется в виду особая (актерская) речь, а не речь человека вообще.**

Здесь уже словосочетание речь актера имеет полностью выраженное значение и закрытую валентность. **Также и относительный суффикс СК в прилагательном актерский отчасти подсказывает нам это решение**. === ЧуднО! Получается, что в предложении "Актёрская речь всегда образна" слово _актёрСКая_ из-за суффикса СК тоже, по-Вашему, следует считать дополнением?

Comment: Уважаемый slava1947!  Считать  прилагательное «актерский»  дополнением не следует, но вы (намеренно, вероятно) пропустили  ключевой смысл моей фразы:  «отчасти суффикс СК может помочь».  Отчасти! Но эта информация может пригодиться вам в другой ситуации, к примеру, чтобы Вы не ошиблись при составлении следующего текста: «Перед  началом фильма  исполнитель гласной роли N рассказал о своей работе. Актерская речь произвела на всех большое впечатление». В этом случае нежелательно использовать сочетание «актерская речь».